# Check whether a value combination from one table exists in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to iterate through every record in a table (SUPPORT) using values for columns 'pmi' and 'transactionid'
and then check whether there is a record with exact same value combination exists in another table (CDETAILS) which too has columns 'pmi' and 'transactionid'.
If a matching record do not exists in CDETAILS, then I need to pick 'pmi' value from SUPPORT table.

select pmi,transactionid from SUPPORT

select pmi,transactionid from CDETAILS

so the query's output will be 'pmi' values from SUPPORT table that do not have a corresponding entry in CDETAILS table.

Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: You need to use a LEFT OUTER join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant 1:

```sql
select distinct pmi 
from (
select pmi,transactionid from SUPPORT
minus
select pmi,transactionid from CDETAILS
);
```

Variant 2:

```
select distinct pmi
from SUPPORT
where (pmi,transactionid) not in (select pmi,transactionid from CDETAILS);
```

Variant 3:

```
select distinct pmi
from SUPPORT s
where not exist(select 0 
                from CDETAILS c 
                where s.pmi=c.pmi 
                and s.transactionid=c.transactionid);
```

Variant 4:

```
select distinct pmi
from SUPPORT s
    left join CDETAILS c 
        on s.pmi=c.pmi 
        and s.transactionid=c.transactionid);
where c.pmi is null;
```

etc...

**NB:** these variant are for not-nulls. In case of nulls you need to determine how exactly you want to compare combinations.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  No nulls to be considered in this scenario.